# A good word for a list with too many items

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm struggling with a word for a list which is very well built, sorted, and organized, but it's a heck of a headache to deal with because there are so many items.

> The list doesn't display old items, to prevent it from becoming______________.

I've toyed with the following words, but they don't seem to fit:

- crowded (can a list be crowded?)
- cluttered (has implication of messy, but the list is very well organized)
- overwhelming (this is more of a person's reaction than a list characteristic)
- jam packed (not proper enough)
- congested (not blocking anything)

Comment: *too long* (yeah, that's two words, but still)

Comment: *Bloated*, perhaps?

Comment: Consider [cumbersome](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cumbersome) or [unwieldy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unwieldy).

Comment: I'd just use "too dense", or maybe "overpopulated" (in context: populate = fill with data).

Comment: "The list doesn't display old items, cuz it grow'd like Topsy." http://cjewords.blogspot.com/2009/08/growd-like-topsy.html

Comment: Perhaps ***unmanageable***.

Answer (score 3):

You apparently don't want the list to *seem* ***endless*** or ***interminable***.

> The list doesn't display old items, to prevent it from becoming
>   ***endless/interminable***.

ODO:

> **[endless](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/endless)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Having or seeming to have no end or limit:
>   ‘the list is endless’
>
> **[interminable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/interminable)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Endless or apparently endless (often used hyperbolically)
>
> ‘After a while these interminable lists acquire a certain ghoulish
>   fascination, prompting a host of other questions.’

Collins:

> **[endless](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/endless)**
>   *adjective*
>   1. having or **seeming to have no end**; eternal or infinite
>   2. **continuing too long** or continually recurring
>
> **[interminable](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/interminable)**
>   *adjective*
>   endless or **seemingly endless because of** monotony or **tiresome length**
>
> Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © Harper Collins Publishers

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to express this would be to say the list is becoming too **long.**

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/long)

> 3 Relatively great in extent:
>
> ‘write a long report’
>
> ‘a long list of candidates’

Answer (score 3):

***unwieldy***

[merriam-webster's definition of unwieldy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unwieldy)

> unwieldy:  not easily managed, handled, or used (as because of bulk, weight, complexity, or awkwardness) :  cumbersome

in your setentence: The list doesn't display old items, to prevent it from becoming *unwieldy*.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using "[overloaded](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/overloaded)" which means:

> having or supplied with too much of something: *The market is already overloaded with car magazines - why would anyone want to produce another one?*

Actual usage:

> It was meant to comprise the name of those about whom suspicion was credible. However, unfortunately, owing to a certain 'indiscriminate use of the autority exercised by branch officers', the list became **overloaded** with names of persons who should not have been on it...

[Source: [MI5 at War 1909-1918](https://books.google.com/books?id=unsACwAAQBAJ&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq="list+became+overloaded"&source=bl&ots=8vL7VFl8WB&sig=K3F4CQbXf5rnhmtlfMvmQWI12nU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo_aq_7ajRAhVLmpQKHaAwDx4Q6AEIGDAA#v=onepage&q=%22list%20became%20overloaded%22&f=false)]

Answer (score -1):

At the end of the sentence, you can probable use the phrase "**a hotchpotch**"

As per Cambridge dictionary, a hotchpotch is "a confused mixture of different things"

The words "**ragbag**" or "**panoply**" are other appropriate options

As per Cambridge dictionary, a panoply is "a wide range or collection of different things". A ragbag is "a confused mixture of different types of things"

Comment: Hmm, never seen it spelled as "hotchpotch". Google ngrams agrees that "hodgepodge" has been the more common spelling for the last 100 years.

Comment: It’s not cleat to me that OP reason for limiting the list is to keep it from becoming a confused mixture of things. It appears to be more a question of keeping the list short and current.

Comment: Hi Matt. The word 'hotchpotch' definitely exists. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hotchpotch

Comment: Jim, if the question is to keep the list short and current, then the word "panoply" would suit the context right ?